# VS Code зачеркивает "event" и пишет в отладке: Ожидалось "while", при написании кода JS. Что это?

Tags: javascript

```
var youAnswers = [];
do { //выводим первый вопрос
    ok = false;
    event = +prompt(works.a00 + works.a1 + works.a2 + "-1 - Exit the Game");
    if (event == -1) {
        break;
    } else {
        ok = isAnswer(works.a0, event);
        if (ok) {
            if (event == 1) {
                youAnswers.push(works.a1);
            } else {
                youAnswers.push(works.a2)
            }
        }
    }
} while (!ok);
switch (event) {
    case 1:
        do {
            ok = false;
            event = +prompt(works.b00 + works.b1 + works.b2 + "-1 - Exit the Game");
            if (event == - 1) {
                break;
            } else {
                ok = isAnswer(works.b0, event);
                if (ok) {
                    if (event == 1) {
                        youAnswers.push(works.b1);
                    } else {
                        youAnswers.push(works.b2)
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (!ok);
        switch (event) {
            case 1:
                do {
                    ok = false;
                    event = +prompt(works.d00 + works.d1 + works.d2 + "-1 = Exit the Game");
                    if (event == -1) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        ok = isAnswer(works.d0, event);
                        if (ok) {
                            if (event == 1) {
                                youAnswers.push(works.d1);
                            } else {
                                youAnswers.push(works.d2)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } while (!ok);

                break;
            case 2:
        }
```

Comment: `while` забыли добавить после `do {} `. Замените на `while (true) { ... }`

Comment: в текущем отрывке кода нет определения переменной `event`. Поэтому может использоваться глобальный объект `event`, который устарел и поэтому может зачеркиваться `IDE`

Comment: `do` без `while` не может существовать

Comment: Grundy, подскажите, пожалуйста, что длать в таком случае?

Comment: в каком из? В вопросе указано два НЕ связанных между собой случая: зачеркиваемый `event`, ошибка про `while`. Для решения первого нужен весь код, чтобы было ясно, какой именно `event` подразумевался. Для решения второго, необходимо знать, что подразумевал автор код, написав указанный цикл, а также посмотреть синтаксисы циклов в js, и выбрать наиболее подходящий

Comment: @Grundy

Это и есть весь код. Начало и чуть-чуть не хватает до конца. Я видеоуроки смотрю, и учитель работает в Brackets. У него не зачеркивает это слово.

Comment: _Начало и чуть-чуть не хватает до конца_ - следовательно - это не весь код :) Причина зачеркивания указана в комментарии выше. Обрати внимание, что зачеркивает именно IDE.

Comment: @Grundy правил код. Теперь точно всё  что есть в уроке. Вот что указано в уведомлении ошибки : Ожидалось "}".

Comment: какая-то ерунда со switch case, последний не закрыт.